# How to split the code for a large GUI?

Tags: delphi, user-interface

I have a program with a large GUI. The GUI is split in several tabs.
The code for managing the GUI (for example one tab contains a full blown Windows Explorer clone) is pretty large.

Which will be the best approach for splitting such a large GUI in multiple files but without having the GUI split in multiple forms (at run time)?

Comment: Each tabsheet is a window. Do you mean multiple forms rather than multiple windows? Sounds like frames are the answer.

Comment: "best approach" sounds a bit "primarily opinion based", maybe could be rephrased. I'd prefer multiple windows which get docked ad runtime, similar line using frames.

Comment: "best approach" could also mean that I get multiple good/bad ideas (that may never cross my mind otherwise) and choose the one that I very personally like (no matter what others are voting)  :)

Comment: The only real disadvantage is that it becomes more difficult to share code across two of such units. But that itself becomes an advantage because it forces you to separate logic into different units.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan that frames are the ideal solution for this. Each tab gets its own frame. I don't see an advantage in docking windows or embedded forms for this. They are harder to use and provide no obvious benefits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use embedded forms. This way you can maintain each one in a separate file, and at run-time they all appear to be part of the same GUI form.

Create a global variable to store the current form:

```
MyForm: TForm;
```

You don't want to auto-create the forms, so remove them from the project options -> Forms auto-create list. Instead, create them dynamically this way:

```
MyForm := TMyForm.Create(Application);
```

Then set the properties as needed, including the following:

I'm assuming you have a panel named something like EmbeddedMyForm_panel on the tabsheet where you want to embed the form. That's what I do, anyway. You could also probably use the TTabSheet directly.

```
with MyForm do begin 
  BorderIcons := []; 
  BorderStyle := bsNone; 
  parent      := EmbeddedMyForm_panel; 
  Align       := alClient; 
  Visible     := true; 
end;
```

I've worked on numerous projects that used this approach very successfully to embed separate forms on tons of tabs inside of one massive GUI.

ADDED: When I've asked why they didn't use frames instead, I was told that with a dozen or more embedded forms on the main form, loading it up with frames would take forever because the IDE would complain about not being able to find the ancestor form for virtually every frame on the form. You need to open all of the frame forms first in order to open the main form without getting any warnings from the IDE. Which is particularly annoying if you simply want to work on the main form itself (eg. edit the main menus) and don't need to deal with any of the frames at all.

Comment: This is an elegant solution! Thanks. There is an article here http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32047 about frames but comparing with your solution is total overkill.

Comment: How are frames overkill? They are no more complex, perhaps less so. And many aspects of the GUI work better with frames.

Comment: Frames were designed to allow you to avoid this solution, because it causes other issues (tab ordering, message processing, focus changes, etc.) that have to be manually dealt with. While I'm not downvoting your answer (because technically it is one solution), I'd highly recommend using frames instead.

Comment: Frames are great if you have a "template" of sorts that you want to place on a bunch of forms. If you only want to embed ONE instance of a form in another, then embedding forms is an easier solution. Frames have a drawback in that when you open a form with a frame on it, the IDE complains if you don't have the frame's source file open in the IDE as well. I've never understood the reasoning behind this, but it discourages me from using frames. Why doesn't it just open the frame file for you if it needs it so badly?

Comment: If memory serves me right, this is the way the TeeChart demo does it. TTabSheet is the parent.

Comment: @Altar -- that's why you don't like FORMS or FRAMES?

Comment: "Frames have a drawback in that when you open a form with a frame on it, the IDE complains" - yep. that is very annoying.